# NSFetchedResultsController returning incorrect section info

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm developing a simple database app that uses core data. Records are displayed in a tableView. To achieve this I make use of a NSFetchedResultsController.

Everything works fine, including deleting, updating etc. The problem arises when I change some code that is clearly not related to my database structure and then run the app again. After that, the tableView (sometimes, not always) stays empty.

What I found out is that the 'numberOfRowsInSection' method returns the incorrect number of objects (0). To get the number of rows in this method I use this code:

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]   objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

However, when I log the result of:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
```

then, the correct amount of objects is shown.

Ergo: the NSFetchedResultsController seems to give me the incorrect sectionInfo. It somehow thinks that section 0 holds 0 objects, while it holds (for example) 7 objects.

Again: the code I change before running the app again, is not related to core data or the fetchedresultscontroller. For example, when I change a font and run the app again, the problem might arise.

Has anyone an idea about where / how to fix this bug?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I perform the fetch:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchrequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entitiy = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"JvBTimeRecords" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchrequest setEntity:entitiy];

//sort descriptors
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetchrequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(project.projectName = %@)", self.searchstring];
[fetchrequest setPredicate:pred];

//fetch only subset. Automatically fetch more as we scroll.
[fetchrequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchrequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"CacheA"];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


return _fetchedResultsController;    
}
```

In ViewDidLoad:

```
NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
     */

    NSLog(@"unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    //exit(-1); //fail
    abort();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you're performing the fetch request?

Comment: I updated the code to show the fetch request.

Comment: @MartinR You might be right. I changed the cacheName to nil and the tableView fills again.

Comment: OK, then it is a duplicate. If you use a cache then you have to delete the cache when the predicate changes.

Comment: But what is the use of a cache if it has to be deleted before every new fetch that is related to the same entity? The idea is: fetch a dataset (in this case JvBTimeRecords) and get some of the data (those that meet specific criteria) out. Right? Why has the cached dataset to be deleted before I change the predicate?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

`id <NSFetchedResultsController> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];`

be this?

`id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];`

Comment: You are completely right that the second line is correct. However, the first line does not compile, so this might be a copy/paste error. - In any case, a wrong declaration can cause compiler errors or warnings, but usually does not change the runtime behaviour due to the dynamic method lookup.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is a typo. I will edit my question.